# JSON.parse is not parsing complete JSON String

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, local

I had this problem in which json.parse is behaving weirdly.
I am reading json from local storage and then saving it to the localstorage in cordova, but when I try to parse it and display its content in console it just shows only one element.

Below is my code.

```
console.log("about to display news: 
" +localStorage.getItem("getNewsLastUpdated"));

var cacheData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eval("(" + 
localStorage.getItem(NewsCacheLocalStorage) + ")")));

console.log("CacheData: " + JSON.stringify(cacheData));
```

below is the screen shot of the same:

[image: The output in the console]

I am reading the file as show in the code below:

```
readCache = function (fs,filename,NewsCacheLocalStorage) {

fs.root.getFile(filename, {}, function(fileEntry) {

    fileEntry.file(function(file) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        console.log("inside file read");
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {

            localStorage.setItem(NewsCacheLocalStorage, this.result);
            console.log("read onloadend: " + 
            localStorage.getItem(NewsCacheLocalStorage) );
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);

    }, errorReadCache);

}, errorReadCache);
```

}

Can any one tell me what is the problem here.

thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you have eval? why string it than parse it??

Comment: why use JSON.stringify with JSON.parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell because you've only presented the data in the form of a screenshot and not a [mcve], but it looks like your data consists of:

- An object literal
- A [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)
- Another object literal

The comma operator:

> evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So it is only natural that you would end up with a single item.

If you want more than one item, put them in an array.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin. It really solved by problem. I put all my content into the array and now it is giving me all the values.